# Event for "activity selected" in WF4 WorkflowDesigner.View

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I want to display some help text in a docked pane for WF4 Activities as the user works with them on the WorkflowDesigner design surface (View). The help text needs to change when the user selects a new Activity.

Is there an event or some other mechanism to be notified when the user selects an item (i.e. a workflow activity) in a rehosted WF4 WorkflowDesigner View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [Selection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.view.selection.aspx) available on designer's editing context. You just have to subscribe to its changes.

```
WorkflowDesigner.Context.Items.Subscribe<Selection>(selection => 
{
    // 'selection' contains various properties including currently selected objects
});
```

Comment: Excellent stuff - worked perfectly. I am relatively new to WF4 and still trying to find things in the namespaces ...